# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: server, permissions, mysql, laravel

I have started my first website (in development) with a simple authentication structure. When I run my website with Homestead, database connection does not work. Actually I can run any mysql command from terminal or mysql workbench, but when I try from browser (homestead.app), I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here my `.env` information:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead 
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I changed the permission and restarted server but same result!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not grant access to that specific user on localhost.  To remedy this, use this:

1. Enter MySQL (watch out: `root` here is the MySQL root, NOT the ubuntu root - you could also use other users having sufficient access level):

> ```
> $ mysql --user=root --password=root_password homestead
> ```

2. In MySQL, grant access like this (in this case, create the user 'homestead'@'localhost' and give him select privileges on everything from DB `homestead`):

> ```
> CREATE USER 'homestead'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
> GRANT SELECT PRIVILEGES ON homestead.* to 'homestead'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
> ```

Refer to the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html) for more info on other options.

This being said, you might preferably post such questions on other sites dedicated to DB administration.

Comment: Security notice: You should not specify password on the command line. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html